# Updating an app using Cordova and Codepush

Tags: cordova, phonegap, code-push

I have a simple content based mobile application for android built using cordova and phonegap. The structure of which is like below

- css
- img
- js
- index.html

I use codepush https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/ to push over the air content updates to my consumers. Over time the structure of the application becomes

- cruise
- vertical
- dominate
- css
- img
- js
- index.html
- support.html
- sync.html

Now when I want to release an .apk update manually (not through the play store) with the same bundle id and version number (or different version) , with probably only a single plugin added. This causes the previously downloaded content to get erased and treats the application as if it is a fresh install rather than an update.

Is there a way wherein I can update the apk and still retain the previously downloaded content.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not, because it is assumed the binary represents a new starting point. It is recommended you stage your rollouts so new binary versions contain the contents of your latest CodePush update prior to posting the APK. This will enable users to start from the location you want them to without the need to force an update. We have discussed true plugin support for the future, but right now CodePush is used to iterate quickly while snapshotting large changes to the store or full APK releases along the way.